# Edge density of triangle-free graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a finite, simple, loopless graph with $|V(G)|=n$. We define its *edge density* as $$ed(G) := \frac{|E(G)|}{n \choose 2}.$$

Moreover we set $$d_n := \text{max}\big\{ed(G): G \text{ is a triangle-free graph with } V(G) = \{1,\ldots, n\} \big\}.$$

Does $\lim_{n\to\infty}d_n$ exist and if yes, what is its value? If not, what is $\lim \text{sup}_{n\to\infty}d_n$? (I would expect this value to be around $2/3$ but I really don't have any idea.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Turan's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem) says that this limit exists and is equal to $\frac{1}{2}$. The graphs that achieve this are the complete bipartite graphs. Moreover, the theorem gives the answer for the more general question of $K_{r+1}$-free graphs, where maximum edge density comes from complete $r$-partite graphs.